# Exception running application application.TipCalculator

Tags: java, javafx

So I was given code from the textbook to use in eclipse and it actually won't run the base code even though I did everything the professor told me to do. Im getting an error exception running application application.TipCalculator and I have no idea what to do. First code snippet is my main, second is my controller, third is my xml file.

TipCalculator.java

```
package application;


import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TipCalculator extends Application {
   @Override
   public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
       Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/TipCalculator.fxml"));

      Scene scene = new Scene(root); // attach scene graph to scene
      stage.setTitle("Tip Calculator"); // displayed in window's title bar
      stage.setScene(scene); // attach scene to stage
      stage.show(); // display the stage
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      // create a TipCalculator object and call its start method
      launch(args); 
   }
}
```

TipCalculatorController.java

```
package application;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class TipCalculatorController { 
   // formatters for currency and percentages
   private static final NumberFormat currency = 
      NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
   private static final NumberFormat percent = 
      NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();
   
   private BigDecimal tipPercentage = new BigDecimal(0.15); // 15% default
   
   // GUI controls defined in FXML and used by the controller's code
   @FXML 
   private TextField amountTextField; 

   @FXML
   private Label tipPercentageLabel; 

   @FXML
   private Slider tipPercentageSlider;

   @FXML
   private TextField tipTextField;

   @FXML
   private TextField totalTextField;

   // calculates and displays the tip and total amounts
   @FXML
   private void calculateButtonPressed(ActionEvent event) {
      try {
         BigDecimal amount = new BigDecimal(amountTextField.getText());
         BigDecimal tip = amount.multiply(tipPercentage);
         BigDecimal total = amount.add(tip);

         tipTextField.setText(currency.format(tip));
         totalTextField.setText(currency.format(total));
      }
      catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
         amountTextField.setText("Enter amount");
         amountTextField.selectAll();
         amountTextField.requestFocus();
      }
   }

   // called by FXMLLoader to initialize the controller
   public void initialize() {
      // 0-4 rounds down, 5-9 rounds up 
      currency.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
      
      // listener for changes to tipPercentageSlider's value
      tipPercentageSlider.valueProperty().addListener(
         new ChangeListener<Number>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov, 
               Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
               tipPercentage = 
                  BigDecimal.valueOf(newValue.intValue() / 100.0);
               tipPercentageLabel.setText(percent.format(tipPercentage));
            }
         }
      );
   }
}
```

TipCalculator.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Slider?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>

<GridPane hgap="8.0" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-
Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" 
xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" 
fx:controller="application.TipCalculatorController">
   <columnConstraints>
      <ColumnConstraints halignment="RIGHT" hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" />
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" />
   </columnConstraints>
   <rowConstraints>
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
   </rowConstraints>
   <children>
      <Label text="Amount" />
      <Label fx:id="tipPercentageLabel" text="15%" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
      <Label text="Tip" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
      <Label text="Total" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
      <TextField fx:id="amountTextField" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
      <TextField fx:id="tipTextField" editable="false" focusTraversable="false" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
      <TextField fx:id="totalTextField" editable="false" focusTraversable="false" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
      <Slider fx:id="tipPercentageSlider" blockIncrement="5.0" max="30.0" value="15.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
      <Button maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#calculateButtonPressed" text="Calculate" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
   </children>
   <padding>
      <Insets bottom="14.0" left="14.0" right="14.0" top="14.0" />
   </padding>
</GridPane>
```

The error im getting is:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/Bandi/eclipse-workspace/TipCalculator/bin/TipCalculator.fxml:41

    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2625)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2603)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3237)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3194)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3163)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3136)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3113)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3106)
    at application.TipCalculator.start(TipCalculator.java:13)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "- Infinity"
    at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2054)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
    at java.base/java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:549)
    at java.base/java.lang.Double.valueOf(Double.java:512)
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.BeanAdapter.coerce(BeanAdapter.java:450)
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.BeanAdapter.put(BeanAdapter.java:258)
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.BeanAdapter.put(BeanAdapter.java:54)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.applyProperty(FXMLLoader.java:520)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processValue(FXMLLoader.java:370)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processPropertyAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:332)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processInstancePropertyAttributes(FXMLLoader.java:242)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:775)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:2838)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2557)
    ... 17 more
Exception running application application.TipCalculator
```

Please help.

Comment: did you defined all of your files in same package? or they are in default package?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/9b5f4963c7f7efdfe5bd4aaac0c3af7e   I believe so, thats a gyazo of the package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firstly you need to change the controller which you added in `application` package:

`note:`  the `/` make it to read from the src folder because they are not in the same package.

**TipController**

change this:

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("TipCalculator.fxml"));
```

to

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/TipCalculator.fxml"));
```

then change the fxml file where you specified the path of controller:

**TipCalculator.fxml**

```
<GridPane hgap="8.0" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.TipCalculatorController">
```

Complete Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Slider?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>

<GridPane hgap="8.0" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.TipCalculatorController">
   <columnConstraints>
      <ColumnConstraints halignment="RIGHT" hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" />
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" />
   </columnConstraints>
   <rowConstraints>
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
   </rowConstraints>
   <children>
      <Label text="Amount" />
      <Label fx:id="tipPercentageLabel" text="15%" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
      <Label text="Tip" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
      <Label text="Total" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
      <TextField fx:id="amountTextField" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
      <TextField fx:id="tipTextField" editable="false" focusTraversable="false" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
      <TextField fx:id="totalTextField" editable="false" focusTraversable="false" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
      <Slider fx:id="tipPercentageSlider" blockIncrement="5.0" max="30.0" value="15.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
      <Button maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#calculateButtonPressed" text="Calculate" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
   </children>
   <padding>
      <Insets bottom="14.0" left="14.0" right="14.0" top="14.0" />
   </padding>
</GridPane>
```

Comment: Where would I put the parent root line at?

Comment: I tried those changes and I still got the same error, I appreciate the help though.

Comment: try to update the code with new changes you applied to the code.

Comment: @cscstudent77 Updated the code, the problem was with your fxml file , so I added the complete fxml file

Comment: Done and done, although I don't have enough reputation for it to show up haha